# printf style "%0*d" % (m, n) -- what's the equivalent form if using mapping keys ("%???d" % { "width": m, "num": n })

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to format a long line involving quite a some vars so I'm using the mapping key style formatting. (And personally I don't like `str.format()`. :)

I tried a lot but failed to find out what the correct syntax should be.

---

With a tuple param it works fine:

```
>>> width = 6
>>> num = 123
>>>
>>> '%0*d' % (width, num)
'000123'
```

I failed to figure out how to do it with a dict param:

```
>>> '%(width)0*d' % dict(width=width, num=num)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
>>>
>>> '%(width)(num)0*d' % dict(width=width, num=num)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: unsupported format character '(' (0x28) at index 8
>>>
>>> '%(width)0*(num)d' % dict(width=width, num=num)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

For now I'm using some workaround. Just curious if this is possible or it's not supported at all.

Comment: If you have python3.6 or higher you can use f-strings, not sure if i understood correctly but maybe what you're looking for is: `f"{width}0*d{num}` ? I can help you more if you add what you have and what's the output you wish to have.

Comment: @Youyoun: that won't work.

Comment: This works though: `f"%0{width}d" % num`

Comment: Oh !!! the output he's trying to get is "000123", if that's the case then simply: `f"{num:>0{width}}"`

Comment: aah. I was trying using f string but could not do it. Thanks I got to learn something from the OP's comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's not supported. Found this in [The Python Library Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) (see the last sentence):

> When the right argument is a dictionary (or other mapping type), then the formats in the string *must* include a parenthesised mapping key into that dictionary inserted immediately after the `'%'` character. The mapping key selects the value to be formatted from the mapping. For example:
>
> ```
> >>> print('%(language)s has %(number)03d quote types.' %
> ...       {'language': "Python", "number": 2})
> Python has 002 quote types.
> ```
>
> **In this case no `*` specifiers may occur in a format (since they require a sequential parameter list).**

Answer (score 0):

If the output you're trying to get is: `000123`, then look into f-strings (if python version >= 3.6):

`f"{num:>0{width}}"` yields `000123`

#### Explanation

You use f-strings by writing your var between brackets. You can format the string between brackets by adding options to it like so `{num:options}`. An example of a pretty common options is .2f which sets the floating point for floats to 2 decimals (Ex: `f"{0.0565:.2f}" -> 0.06`.

The options I used is ">0*int*" means pad to the right using "0" to form a string of length *int*.

More options can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Comment: thanks. i'm trying to figure out how to do it with the printf style formatting.

Comment: @pynexj for your specific case, you could do it this way `"%(width)s%(num)d" % dict(num=num, width="".join(["0" for _ in range(width - len(str(num)))]))`, but it's not using the formatting as it's supposed to.